# JQuery Slide Up and Down is not working with Slow Effects

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a page in which I have added Jquery SlideUp and SlideDown functionalities. It is working fine but slow effect/animation is not working. Please check my code below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {            
                $("#trHeader").on("click", function() {
                    $("#data").slideToggle("slow");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr id="trHeader">
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="data">
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>User1</td>
                    <th>Male</th>
                    <td>test.user1@gmail.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>User2</td>
                    <th>Female</th>
                    <td>test.user2@gmail.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>User3</td>
                    <th>Female</th>
                    <td>test.user3@gmail.com</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have added my code at below URL as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/Sanjay7035/e1qjmo9L/2/